# Why can't I start a transaction while looping a result set?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, pdo

I have the following PDO code (PHP 5.6, Microsoft SQL Server 2014):

```
$st = $db->prepare('SELECT TOP 5 * FROM table');
$st->execute();
while ($st->fetch()) {
    var_dump($db->beginTransaction());
    //$db->rollback();
}
```

The result is as follows:

```
bool(false)
bool(false)
bool(false)
bool(false)
bool(true)
```

I was expecting all true results, but the transaction is not started until the last record was retrieved. Why can't I start a transaction while looping through a result set?

Switching [MARS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131686.aspx) on or off does not seem to have any effect.

Comment: Reading the documents it seems that there is a mode that you can switch between, it seems it waits until its finished first. Maybe try turning auto commit mode on. http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.begintransaction.php

Comment: Why would you even start a transaction at every loop iteration?

Comment: Background: need to manipulate a few tables for each row in a result set ('actions'), and want to wrap that in a transaction for each action to be able to rollback one action on errors and still continue with other actions.

Comment: Alright, then here's a hunch on why (I do not use MSSQL so I won't post an answer). It's because you are using `while($sth->fetch())`. The cursor isn't "released" until traversing is done, that's why it works for the last record and not for previous ones. I'd use `$records = $sth->fetchAll(); foreach($records as $record) {.....` instead and try with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the cursor is open, you cannot start a new transaction when using MSSQL. Calling closeCursor() on the result set or retrieving consuming all the results returned by the query frees that cursor and allows transactions once again.

Also; beginTransaction() returning false will also yield an error that can be retrieved using errorInfo(); saying:

> New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session.